# ¿Cómo sustituir múltiples caracteres por uno solo?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, procesamiento-de-texto

Estoy intentando separar una cadena cada vez que se tope con un separador como:

- "
- #
- $
- %
- &
- /
- (
- )
- *

etc. pero no sé cómo hacer para hacer para reconozca todo junto en una cadena.

Intenté usar sed para todos los caracteres especiales pero solo reconoce 2 y aparece la cadena repetida 2 veces al final con un error que dice "opción desconocida".

```
#!/bin/bash
echo escriba cadena
read c
echo "$c" | sed -e 's/;/\n/g'| sed -e 's/:/\n/g' ...
```

por ejemplo si pongo:

```
hola; como estas:tengo%un$problema
```

Quiero que quede así:

```
hola
 como estas
tengo
un
problema
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con tu intento, no estabas tan lejos de lo que querías.

En la siguiente publicación trataremos de indagar respecto a varias estrategias.

Trataremos de usar las siguientes herramientas:

- **sed**
- **awk**
- **perl**
- Tanto **Zsh** como **Bash**

En todos los ejemplos, el resultado es el siguiente:

```
$ <cualquier estrategia tomada>
hola
 como estas
tengo
un
problema
```

## 1. Utilizando `sed`

Tu aproximación con `sed`, estaba  muy cercana a lo que buscábamos, sólo que necesitábamos habilitar las expresiones regulares extendidas con el parámetro `-r` y utilizar una expresión regular muy sencilla.

Veamos que sucedería con aquello que mencionamos:

```
$ sed -r 's/["#$%&/()*:;]/\n/g' <<< 'hola; como estas:tengo%un$problema'
hola
 como estas
tengo
un
problema
```

Con la sencilla expresión regular `["#$%&/()*:;]`, le indicamos a `sed` que busque cualquiera de los caracteres dentro del *bracket*.

En la segunda parte, le indicamos que reemplace lo que encontró con un salto de línea.

### 1.1 Variante con caracteres alfanuméricos y espacios

Una idea que nos puede agradar es que no sólo ciertos caracteres sean los que querramos sustituir, sino que ciertos caracteres **no** querramos sustituir.

Por ejemplo, en el caso planteado, podríamos pedir que todo lo que **no** sea tanto alfanumérico como un *blank character*, es decir, tab o espacio, sea sustituido por un salto de línea:

```
$ sed -r 's/[^[:alnum:][:blank:]]/\n/g' <<< 'hola; como estas:tengo%un$problema'
```

La selección de este tipo de caracteres la hacemos con las clases de caracter `[:alnum:]` y `[:blank:]` que se mencionan en [`regex(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) y que se describen con mas detalle en [`isalpha(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html).

## 2. Utilizando `awk`

Otra herramienta útil que podemos utilizar es `awk`.

Utilicémosla explotando la funcionalidad de la variable `RS`.

En primera instancia, utilicemos cada caracter deseado como separador. **Esto nos lleva a ahorrar la sustitución por el salto de línea**, ya que la variable `RS` es utilizada para imprimir registro por registro según un patrón o un caracter, así que ya lo tendría supuesto:

```
$ awk -v RS='["#$%&/()*:;]' '{print}' <<< 'hola; como estas:tengo%un$problema'
```

Podemos aplicar lo mismo con lo visto anteriormente en `sed`, es decir, el hecho de que todo lo que no se ni alfanumérico ni un *blank character* sea considerado un reparador de registro:

```
$ awk -v RS='[^[:alnum:][:blank:]]' '{print}' <<< 'hola; como estas:tengo%un$problema'
```

Como bien expande @fedorqui en los comentarios, es posible todavía acortar más el comando simplemente poniendo un 1 en lugar de `{print}`:

```
$ awk -v RS='[^[:alnum:][:blank:]]' '1' <<< 'hola; como estas:tengo%un$problema'
```

## 3. Utilizando Perl

Una ventaja de utilizar `perl` sobre las demas herramientas es que **podemos usar con mayor comodidad los [caracteres de clase](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)**.

En lugar de utilizar `[:alnum:]`, mejor `\w`; en lugar de `[:blank:]` o `[:space:]`, mejor `\s` (que no es lo mismo que `[:blank:]`).

```
$ perl -lpe 's/[^\w\s]/\n/g' <<< 'hola; como estas:tengo%un$problema'
```

## 4. Utilizando las características de nuestra shell

Las shells (no sé si todas) están equipadas con herramientas muy útiles; estas (al menos puedo hablar de [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) y [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion)) tienen una funcionalidad llamada *parameter expansion* que permite ejecutar operaciones sobre —como bien dice el nombre— los parámetros.

Primero declaremos nuestra variable con el contenido deseado:

```
$ var1='hola; como estas:tengo%un$problema'
```

Podemos lograr lo que queríamos desde un inicio en Bash, utilicemos:

```
$ echo "${var1//[$;:*%()\#&\/\"]/$'\n'}"
```

O en **Zsh**:

```
$ echo "${var1//[$;:*%()#&\/\"]/\n}"
```

Hay que notar que en el caso de Bash nos referimos al salto de línea como `$'\n'`, a diferencia de, como hicimos en Zsh, `\n`. Esto es por [como Bash trata lo que se encuentra entrecomillado](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

Comment: nótese que en Awk, `{print}` puede simplificarse en apenas `'1'`. Buena respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

Usa el comando `tr`, que **tr**aduce caracteres:

```
tr '[;%"#$&//)*:]' '\n'
```

En el corchete le indicamos toda la serie de caracteres a "coger" y con `\n` le decimos que los sustituya por saltos de línea.

Con tu ejemplo:

```
$ tr '[;%"#$&//)*:]' '\n' <<< "hola; como estas:tengo%un$problema"
hola
 como estas
tengo
un
```